# Restricting user entry in Entry field in Tkinter without 'disabled' method

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to restrict the user from entering into the tkinter Entry field. *But I dont want to disable to the widget entirely.*
The main reason is I have 4924 commands that include the insertion of characters into the Widget, I cant just change every single of those line of code to the following. I only have enough time to do school.

```
field.configure(state='mormal')
field.insert(0, "example word")
field.configure(state='disabled')
```

I would really appreciate any way (including inefficient ways too) that helps me with this issue.
My source code is has approximately has 10100 lines of code btw.( I am making an advanced calculator)

**Maybe is there any alternative to the entry field that can help me achieve this mammoth of a problem.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the way is to create a custom class inherited from `Entry` and override the `insert()`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
...

class MyEntry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)
        # make it disabled, but with black on white like in normal state
        self.config(state='disabled', disabledforeground='black', disabledbackground='white')

    def insert(self, pos, value):
        self.config(state='normal')
        super().insert(pos, value)
        self.config(state='disabled')

    def delete(self, first, last=None):
        self.config(state='normal')
        super().delete(first, last)
        self.config(state='disabled')

...

field = MyEntry(...)  # use MyEntry instead of tk.Entry
...
```

It still uses 'disabled' state, but you don't need to change the other parts of your application.

Comment: First, Your solution is amazing!, But unfortunately even though it solved my problem(disallowing users to enter in entry field without 'disable' method). There is a new issue, That is. Now I am unable to perform the delete method. I am pretty sure it is a simple work within the MyEntry class, but I am a newbie and I dont know about classes in python yet. I might work around it in the future. Thanks .Nice answer again.

Comment: just figured it out @acw1668. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Duffy, if you want to use the `delete` method as well, make a delete function inside the class and do the same thing that @acw1668 did, but replace insert with delete.

Comment: @Duffy Answer updated with `delete()` added.

Comment: @Duffy, I've uploaded an answer that might help you. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the user to type anything into the entry widget throughout the whole program, you can just do this:

```
my_entry.bind("<Key>", lambda a: "break")
```

This will ignore any key press from the user into the entry widget, but you will still be able to insert and delete text from the entry widget whenever you'd like to.

Comment: can you explain what the 'a:'  just besides lambda is for? Just curious.

Comment: @Duffy, a is for the positional argument that the "break" function takes. You can name it anything you'd like. If you don't use a positional argument in this case, you will get an error